# Highlight cells of datagridview with different values in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, paint, highlight

I have two datagridview.
With same column headers but different cell data.

first One is called grid_db
 second one is calld grid_statement.

If the value of grid_db is not same as that of grid_statement at cell[j] i must have the cells highlighted (red).
i tried the following

```
int no_of_col = grid_db.Columns.Count;
int j;

for (j = 0; j < no_of_col;)
{ 
    //if statement value is null replace with ZERO
    if (grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value != null &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString()))
    {
        B = grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }


    //if db value is null replace with zero
    if (grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value != null &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString()))
    {
         A = grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }

    if (A != B)
    {
        grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

        j++;
    }
}
```

But it does not works.The above codes highlights ALL the columns of both grids.
Help ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and it works for me, the only thing i've changed is the for loop to increment on every pass, otherwise  it can easily be infinite (it only works for 1st row because that's what your code does):

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        grid_db.DataSource = new[]
        {
            new{
               id = 1,
               tekst="a"
                },
                new
                    {
                        id=2,
                        tekst="b"
                    }
        }.ToList();
        grid_statement.DataSource = new[]
        {
            new{
               id = 1,
               tekst="b"
                },
                new
                    {
                        id=2,
                        tekst="c"
                    }
        }.ToList();
         Load += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        HighlightRows();
                    };
    }
    private void HighlightRows()
    {
        int no_of_col = grid_db.Columns.Count;
        int j;
        var B = "";
        var A = "";
        for (j = 0; j < no_of_col; j++)
        {
            //if statement value is null replace with ZERO
            if (grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value != null &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString()))
            {
                B = grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
            //if db value is null replace with zero
            if (grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value != null &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString()))
            {
                A = grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
            if (A != B)
            {
                grid_db.Rows[0].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                grid_statement.Rows[0].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var differentCells = 
       grid_db.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .SelectMany(r=>r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>())
                   .Where(c=>!grid_statement[c.ColumnIndex,c.RowIndex].Value.Equals(c.Value));
//loop through all the cells and make them red
foreach(var cell in differentCells)
  cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Does it work for you? It is just a simplified variation of his code. I tried both his and your code and I'm still unable to color that cells. I can't find the reason.

Comment: bahh .. No still no outcomes. His codes also paints all the cells red.